# JPA query ends up with null values

Tags: java, postgresql, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

Long story short:

- `Recipe` contains

  ```
  @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE}, mappedBy = "recipe")
  private Set<RecipeRow> rows = new HashSet<>();
  ```
- `Row` contains:

  ```
  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)`
  @JoinColumn(name = "recipe_id")
  private Recipe recipe;`
  ```
- The `Row` extends a mapped superclass with a tree structure (i.e. it contains a mapped `parent` field which is of same type)

Right before the entity manager merge (of the recipe) all rows (and their information) are there. When it merges, it throws this (it's with regards to the row!!!):

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "name" violates
    not-null constraint Detail: Failing row contains (11, 2015-08-22 13:53:33.276, 
    304170813849900523, 0, null, null, null, null, null, null, 1000, null, 
    null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null).
```

which is pretty much impossible because all mandatory fields are there.

Also, the ID sequence (of the row table) is increased, but no rows are persisted in the DB (postgres).

Am I missing something here?
Is my question too broad?

---

**Edit 1:**

- The JPA UID in the error message DOES NOT correspond to either of my recipe rows which are being saved. Where does this ghost entity come from?
- All mandatory fields are filled in the rows before saving!

Comment: any column which not allowed `NULL` and you pass `NULL` to that

Comment: @SubodhJoshi Well that's the point. All of my entities are valid whilst debugging, but ends up with all null values!

Comment: Means You are not giving `NULL` and added by JPA as a default value?

Comment: You mention your `Row` has a superclass - can you tell us about that table structure too?  IIRC there's a JPA polymorphism style which works by flattening all the fields into one table which might cause errors like this.  Is "name" a column name in `Row`, or its superclass, or one of the other subclasses?

Comment: @hugh `NamedEntity` -> `TreeEntity` -> `Row`, so row is a leaf subclass. `name` is found in the first one, the parent for the tree structure is mapped in the second class (which is a `@MappedSuperclass`)

Comment: @hugh Got it. Check answer.

Comment: Great!  I really wouldn't call that a *beginner* mistake though :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so this was a beginner's mistake, and also a stupid one.

The rows have a tree structure, right? And the saved collection contained ALL of them, as flat tree (ie list).

The problem is that the top rows had the abstract root as parent (which isn't transient), and the abstract root was trying to map itself.

Of course I didn't notice this in the debugging, because I was only looking at the rows, and at their mandatory fields, but not at the parent (which isn't mandatory).

Yep...